# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на лайк менялся цвет навсегда и цифра тоже, и так же на дизлайк

Tags: javascript

```
                    <div class="like">

                        <h1>144<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
                        <h1><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>2</h1>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: что значит навсегда?

Comment: @BearVorkuta, видимо, чтобы сохранялся при перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: @humster_spb  скорее всего да, но в любом случаем информации маловато ))

Comment: @BearVorkuta да и без БД такое всё равно не реализовать, а автор вряд ли это понимает